# What is the best development path for someone with no ARM experience to learn a powerful embedded system?

Tags: embedded, arm, bare-metal

I want to design LOW COST embedded systems that need significant compute power, for example real time HD video compression.

For someone with experience in PIC and Atmel architectures, but no ARM or Linux experience, what is the best path to a "powerful" embedded system?

By powerful I mean >=32 bit processor with a clock rate of >=500MHZ and lots of internal RAM and flash.

The obvious first choice is Linux running on an ARM processor.  My perception of this path is that it is long and difficult, and running Linux typically requires external RAM and/or non volatile memory such as a flash drive, not to mention supporting hardware like a PMIC (power management IC).   All this supporting infrastructure is expensive.

Bare-metal ARM would eliminate the Linux learning curve but my perception is that most ARM chips are not fully documented and even if they are development is difficult due to the complexity of the ARM architecture.

What are some other good options?

Comment: ARM systems tend to have much better documentation than Microchip PIC products.  Hard to compete with Atmel, of course Atmel has a number of arm platforms...Clifford mentioned the raspberry pi, which is an exception to the documentation rule (as are anything awinner), but has a strong following and some docs and is super simple to use (compared to others).  The cortex-m4 are the more powerful of the microcontrollers but you may need more than that so look at the raspi and the beagle bone.

Comment: This type of question is too much about opinions and subjective advice and not concerete enough for the Stack Overflow format.  The topic area is appropriate though, so specific issues that were more along the lines of "what is needed to implement x" would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

ARM micro-controllers are generally fully documented. ARM licencees producing SoCs for their own internal use may not document the SoC of course, but equally you would not normally be able to purchase a development board with one of those. One exception is the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/), it uses a Broadcom ARM11 SoC and can be over-clocked to 1GHz (from a default of 700MHz).  While the chip's GPU in particular is not publicly documented, it is supported by at least some of the operating systems available for it - the most commonly used being *Raspbian* - a port of Debian Linux.  It is *very* low cost - probably the biggest bang-per-buck available for a Linux platform.